# Is there an FFT implementation that is NEON optimized for double precision numbers?

Tags: android, performance, arm, fft, neon

We are running an algorithm on Android devices that requires multiple FFT calculations per second, we would like to reduce the battery consumption by using a more efficient version of FFT.

At the moment we are using Eigen's version which I believe is using kissFFT as the backend. I have also tried compiling ARM's HPC libraries for Android without much success (though testing on the server they were 3-4 times faster than Eigen). I am also researching FFTW's implementation but it seems like it only supports 32 bit neon operations even though it's supposed to be Aarch64 optimized.

I understand that arm-v8a added double precision operations to the NEON instruction set so it should be possible, but is there any implementation out there that does it?
Am I wrong and it is simply impossible to do FFT on double numbers in arm-v8a?

Comment: You shouldn't ask any "where to find something" question here. But yes, it's doable on `aarch64` since it's IEEE754 compliant which dictates `double` to be mandatory. Why don't you write one yourself and contribute? If you can't, you should hire someone who can instead of looking for freebees.

Comment: At the risk of being patronising, are you sure you need double precision ? Most real-world signals (images, sound, etc) only require single precision for FFT, but perhaps you're working with some other kind of data ? The reason I ask is that both performance and availability of FFT implementations will be much better if you can relax this requirement.

Comment: @PaulR You are right. I'd even go for q15 fixed-point math for signals since NEON has `rdmulh` sort of instructions.

Comment: Oh no, I'm not looking for freebies. One of my approaches was to try and understand if fftw supports 64bit neon, which if was possible would definitely not be free. The next option would probably be hiring a contractor to write this since I don't have the skills for that, but I wanted to know whether I'm searching for something that isn't even possible.

Comment: We are also looking to see if we can move the algorithm to 32 bit too improve performance, I'll look into what is q15 fixed point math to see if it helps.